# NetBeans 6.9 and javaw.exe uses > 50% of CPU

Tags: netbeans, cpu, javaw

When i work with NetBeans 6.9 for PHP the javaw.exe is occupying more then 50% of CPU and about 450mb ram (ram is not really the problem) but CPU tend to overheat.

I had jdk6.5 for 64bit sys and now updated to latest jdk6.21 but it is the same, the CPU is always near 100%

is there a solution to this high requirements of javaw.exe?

OS: Win7 64bit

---

### UPDATE:

I installed the NetBeans 6.7.1 the one that worked EXCELLENT to compare with 6.9.

so: 
6.7.1 less memory usage by javaw.exe then 6.9 but cpu still in use > 50% nonstop

then:
I installed the JDK6_21 32bit cause i had 64bit and in the config  (netbeans.conf) file set the path of the 32bit JDK.

6.9 less memory CPU still to high
6.7.1 less memory NO CPU usage when idle

SO im gonna downgrade to the 6.7.1 because it works for me and i dont really need the 6.9 cause i dont really use the new features that offers.

btw. 6.8 was crashing with no reason, so that option is out.

Comment: That's one of the reasons I moved to Eclipse. :p

Answer (score 1):

You could configure Netbeans to run java.exe instead of javaw.exe, and see if the behavior is still the same.

If it's the same, this is clearly a Netbeans problem, so I would suggest reporting this problem to Netbeans, since this is the way bugs get usually fixed :).

Comment: how do i set the netbeans to use java.exe and not javaw.exe ?

Comment: @Casper: I checked the latest NB, and it looks like the latest version does not allow this anymore :(. For windows, there's only a netbeans.exe (no alternative batch file for starting) that has no possibility to change from it's settings all the start params as before :(. So the only thing left for you is to report this bug to Netbeans. Since this looks like a serious bug, they could release an update quite soon.

Comment: well, i came up with non-complimentary solution for netbeans, ill use the old 6.7.1 that worked in every possible way, the one that showed me the way far from eclipse :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should consider doing on Netbeans (and Eclipse... and $insertOtherIDE) is to turn off automatic project indexing, compile on save, and other things that cause lots of work to happen in the background without your prompting.

In Netbeans 6.9, external scanning/indexing tends to be the biggest culprit when dealing with projects of considerable size.  Try disabling it by (and these instructions are for the Mac, I assume they are similar on Windows)

1. Go to Preferences
2. Click on Miscellaneous
3. Click on the Files Tab
4. Deselect "Enable auto-scanning of sources"

After this you can force NB to re-scan by clicking `Source->Scan For External Changes` in the menu (might be Mac specific, again).

See if that helps you out at all...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Win7 64bit). Everything was working, but suddenly (I think after refactoring some stuff) javaw.exe was constantly using the cpu.

After clearing the netbeans cache, everything was working again (delete the contents of the cache folder and restart Netbeans).

```
%UserProfile%\.netbeans\6.9\var\cache\
```

I had to do this before after getting strange errors in Netbeans and most of the time it solved the problems. I think sometimes it just gets out of sync.